# Как задеплоить Spring boot WAR?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Всем привет.

Разбираюсь со Спрингом. На примере http://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/
сделал свое приложение. На эмбадед Томкэте все грузится прекрасно. Стоит мне добавить packaging - war и попытаться задеплоить варник на внешний Томкэт - в логе - 
Start is in progress...
start?path=/MSGAdmin
OK - Started application at context path /MSGAdmin

но по факту по этому адресу меня встречает 404.

Мой pom.xml :

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>MSGAdmin</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<name>MSGAdmin</name>
```

Подскажите, пож, как задеплоить на внешний Томкэт?

Comment: Не имел дело с деплоем бута в томкэт, и, наверное, сейчас скажу совсем поперек, но на самом деле джарник с вложенным сервером в тыясчу раз лучше варника. У него куда больше возможностей, из него легко сделать 12-factor app, он может масштабироваться простым выполнением одной команды на соседней машине, а со статичными серверами всегда очень много лишней мороки. В инженерных кругах есть понятия [cattle и pet](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/pets-vs-cattle) - и подход с джарником делает очень многое для перехода pet в cattle.

Comment: Спасибо, осознание постепенно приходит)

Comment: Только теперь всплыла проблема, запускаю приложение через IDE - все работает, Html, js и css подтягиваются. Когда через java - jar app.jar пробую - все расивости не грузятся и тянется только один из *.html

Comment: Вот деполой Spring Boot в бизнес-облако на их сервер. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328762/how-to-host-spring-boot-application-with-postgresql-on-the-could-jelastic/43370194#43370194

Answer (score 3):

Приведи структура получившегося war'ника, версию tomcat'а на который деплоишь и то, как деплоишь (через IDE, кладешь в каталог webapp или ещё как-то).
По имеющейся информации, но сначала настоятельная рекомендация. Spring boot предназначен для приложений, имеющих встроенный сервер. Ты же кладешь в сервер приложение, которое хранит вложенный сервер. Если ты хочешь организовать приложение таким образом, то тебе надо разбивать его на 3(!) приложения:

1. Jar'ник, хранящий классы контроллеров, ресурсы, другие бины и т.д, который реализуют логику, при это никак не завязанный на spring boot
2. Jar'ник для запуска приложения из коробки, который хранит в себе встроенный сервер, класс-лаунчер (@SpringBootApplication) и jar'ник из пункта 1.
3. War'ник, для запуска приложения из под сервера, который тоже хранит в себе jar'ник из пункта 1 и класс-лаунчер ([WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) или другие альтернативы).

Что касательно твоей ситуации. Во-первых, tomcat по умолчанию добавляет приложению контекст, соответствующий имени war'ника. В твоём случае это MSGAdmin-0.1.0 (или без номера версии). И если ты раньше к **index.html** стучался по **localhost:8080/index.html**, то теперь надо **localhost:8080/MSGAdmin-0.1.0/index.html** (или **localhost:8080/MSGAdmin/index.html**). Если же дело касается динамических ресурсов (обращение к контроллерам и т.д.), помимо изменения адреса, легко может упасть [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), по причине описанной в самом начале. Но это уже 500-я ошибка.
Ну и собственно [сслыка на официальную документацию](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging). Собственно в ней `<scope>provided</scope>` и означет, что сам встроенный сервер не попадает в war'ник.

Comment: Разочаровался в Spring Boot(, думаешь, стоит перейти на большой Спринг и извращения с бутом не стоит свеч? Понравилось отсутствие утомительных context.xml и  web.xml. А по структуре - деплою через IDE (Netbeans 8.1) хотя и пробовал ложить webapp томкэта , Tomcat 8. Все очень похоже на то что ты рассказываешь, JS и HTML удалось поднять, но контроллер на AngularJS не обрабатывает запросы с формы

Comment: web.xml теперь не обязателен, context.xml вообще относится только к tomcat'у. Если тебе не надо ничего из java-ee, а только spring, то юзай boot'ы. Spring кстати может распознавать многие jsr-аннотации. Тут вопрос предпочтения.